# Compaction causes Write to hang until finished

Tags: c++, leveldb

I need to write lots of data to a leveldb database as quickly as possible.

Periodically, leveldb starts 'compaction' to merge the database files together. While compaction is running, any calls to `DB::Write` won't return until compaction has finished, causing long pauses at regular intervals.

This is not the desired (or expected) result as I was under the impression that compaction happens on a separate thread.

This is especially bad for me because I write to the database on all available threads, so when these pauses occur, CPU usage spikes to 100% even though the threads are just waiting for compaction to finish. This is what I want to avoid, 100% usage from just waiting...

---

Pseudo-code:

```
//open database earlier in program
leveldb::DB *db;
leveldb::DB::Open(options, filePath, &db);

//...

//inside each worker thread, create data, put in write batch
leveldb::WriteBatch wb;

//...

//lots of data etc
wb.Put(sliceKey, sliceData);

//call write
leveldb::WriteOptions writeOptions;
writeOptions.sync = false;
db->Write(writeOptions, &wb); //HANGS ONLY IF COMPACTION IS RUNNING, can take 15+ seconds
```

---

Things I've tried:

- Set `WriteOptions::sync` to `false` (It was false to begin
  with, appears to have no effect)
- Called `DB::Put` instead of `DB::Write` (aka, not using a `WriteBatch`, same problem)
- Sent any calls to `DB::Write` in a single thread (prevented CPU usage from reaching 100%, but slowed the whole thing down 2x. Not acceptable.)
- Searching through the leveldb source code to understand why this is happening (idk)
- Call `SuspendCompaction` which removes the pauses, but now it doesn't compact the database...

---

Any insight regarding this issue would be much appreciated!

NOTE: Here's a good blog post that summarizes how compaction works on a background thread http://tonyz93.blogspot.com/2016/11/leveldb-source-reading-3-compaction.html

Comment: If you use all but one core, does that help at all?  Also, what kind of disk drive are you using?  Could be that you are IO limited and a better drive like an NVME SSD would fix that.

Comment: Ryzen 9 3900X, 1TB NVME SSD. The calls to Write happen on 24 threads, but the program still hangs because each thread is paused waiting for Write to return. Each cores usage is still maxed out while they're just waiting. Compaction is supposed to be async afaik. Removing 1 thread would bring usage down 1/24th